# C# - Server-side password protection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sockets, password-protection

I am writing two console applications, a client and a server.
I'm a little stuck at two things, which seemed rather easy at first..

#1: **I want to write a function for the following piece of code, that converts bits to a string, but I cant just figure it out.** The server always crashes when I use it. My function is a little bit different than this one, but that's because my current code has to include the connection information, and I think there's a better way to do it:

```
        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        int k = s.Receive(b);

            string packet = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
            packet = packet + Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
        }
```

I guess the function is not the problem, but how I use it is. Any help would be very much apreciated.

Edit:
I am calling and using it like this:

```
    byte[] b = new byte[100];
    string response = BitConvert(b);

    if (response == "Hi there")
```

#2 **I want the client to álways send a packet just once, with a password.** And if that password doesn't match the password mentioned as a string in the server, it should close the connection with the client.

I know how to send the packet just once, but I don't know how to check the packet in the server just once for each client.

Or in other words, at the moment the server has no way of knowing if the client has already been authenticated. So I guess the client needs to have some sort of socket ID, and the server needs a table with the ID, and a boolean to see if it's autenticated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part, getting the bytes into a string ... how about:

```
byte b[] = new byte[100];
int k = s.Receive(b, b.Length, 0);

string packet = Encoding.ASCII.getString(b, 0, k);
```

Part 2 ... not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks, that's alot faster than what I'm using at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Rob above on part 1 and as for part 2...
Assuming you're using a TCP connection the `System.Net.Sockets` class should handle your 
needs.

If you use either `AcceptSocket` or `AcceptTcpClient` to pull a connection from the incoming connection request queue you'll get a socket or tcpclient that is unique to that connection. simply leave it open until you're done with it. (There are also non-blocking alternatives if your service has other things to do...)

If the client closes it or opens up a new connection the will have to reauthenticate somehow. (This may be by including a token that you generate for them when they first authenticate - that's your only option if you're using UDP connections).

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll take a look at that.

It would be really easy if there was a run_once command of some sort. Then I would just put a boolean in my mysql table to say if they logged in securely.

Comment: It all depends how your service is going to be accessed. If all the transactions are going to be over a short period of time (a few minutes) then using TCP is the way to go since it will handle the remembering of authentication for you. (Same connection = still authenticated).

If, however, there are going to be gaps of more than about 5 minutes then the TCP session will time out so you'll need to use the token method.